# Unhashable type 'dict' when trying to send an Elasticsearch

Tags: python, api, elasticsearch

I keep on getting the following error in Python

> Exception has occurred: TypeError unhashable type: 'dict'

on line 92

```
  "should": [],
  "must_not": []
```

This is the query string

```
res = es.search(
                scroll = '2m',
                index = "logstash-*",
                body = {
{
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "src_ip.keyword",
        "size": 50,
        "order": {
          "1": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "1": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "src_ip.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "script_fields": {},
  "docvalue_fields": [
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "format": "date_time"
    },
    {
      "field": "flow.start",
      "format": "date_time"
    },
    {
      "field": "timestamp",
      "format": "date_time"
    },
    {
      "field": "tls.notafter",
      "format": "date_time"
    },
    {
      "field": "tls.notbefore",
      "format": "date_time"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": 1555777931992,
              "lte": 1558369931992,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
})
```

Comment: `body = { {` at the start is attempting to have a dictionary as a key to the outer dictionary. Is that intentional? You can't do that. I think you just need to get rid of the outer dictionary.

Comment: **Query** - not "quarry" .....

Comment: @Carcigenicate, actually the outer {} would be a set literal in this case. Of course it still means dictionary is unhashable and cannot be the item in a set.

Answer (score 0):

the value of `body` is a set (`{ }` without key-value is a set literal, e.g., `{1,2}` is a set). Inside this set you have a dictionary.

Items in a set have to be hashable, and dictionary isn't.
As the comment from @Carcigenicate says, it seems like a typo of having `{{ }}` instead of `{ }` for the value of `body`.

Elasticsearch [documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/) shows that body should be a dictionary.
More about sets from [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)